# c++ template to iterate through the map

Tags: c++

I have constructed a template for arbitrary template iterator, however it doesn't work and I couldn't figure out why... Could someone help me with it?

The template:

```
template<typename type1,typename type2>
void printmap(map<type1,type2>&thismap)
{
    for(map<type1,type2>::iterator it = thismap.begin(); it != thismap.end(); ++it)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

The error shown is:

[image]

Could someone help me with that? Thank you:)

Comment: BTW, your IDE shows you the answer... Missing `typename`

Comment: yea... I am very new to c++ and thus I am rather not sure what that exactly means the first time I saw it....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Easy breezy beautiful, typename:

```
for(typename map<type1,type2>::iterator it = thismap.begin(); it != thismap.end(); ++it)
```

The reason being:

> Before a qualified dependent type, you need typename

See [Here](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~driscoll/typename.html) for details.

Alternately, you could use a typedef outside the loop to make it more readable:

```
typedef typename map<type1, type2>::iterator mapIt;
for(mapIt it = thismap.begin(); it != thismap.end(); ++it){
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have c++11 of higher you can also change

```
for(map<type1,type2>::iterator it = thismap.begin(); it != thismap.end(); ++it)
```

to

```
for(auto it = thismap.begin(); it != thismap.end(); ++it)
```

Comment: ... if you have a new enough compiler

Answer (score 1):

The compiler does not know that `map<type1,type2>::iterator` is a type.
Just add **typename**.

```
template<typename type1,typename type2>
void printmap(map<type1,type2>&thismap)
{
    for(typename map<type1,type2>::iterator it = thismap.begin(); it != thismap.end(); ++it)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: @0x499602D2 You are right,I wanted to write `typename`. Thanks for the comment, I changed it.